# Find the number of real roots of the following equation

Tags: trigonometry

Question: The  number of real roots of the equation
$$2\cos\left( \frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)=2^x+2^{-x}$$ is
(i) $0$ $\qquad$ (ii) $1$   $\qquad$(iii)  $2$    $\qquad$ (iv)  $\infty.$

I have tried in the following way:

$$2\cos\left( \frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)=2^x+2^{-x}\implies \cos\left( \frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)=\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}.$$
What can I do after this?

Answer (score 1):

by AM-GM we have $$\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}\geq \sqrt{2^x\cdot 2^{-x}}=1$$
can you proceed?
and $$\left|\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)\right|\le 1$$

Comment: How does this help, indeed cosine has this range

Comment: it helps since it must be the left and the right-hand side equal to $1$

Comment: Oh I see thanks.

Comment: that is the trick for solving such equations